# Can PostDiscoveryFilter filter parametrized test cases of JUnit5?

Tags: java, junit5

I want to filter parametrized test-case with definite param; How can I do this ?

For example I have such test class:

```
public class SomeClassTest {

    @ParameterizedTest
        @ValueSource(strings = {"0,0", "1,1", "2,1", "3,2", "4,3", "5,5", "6,8"})
        void testFibParam(String arg) {
           //some code
           If(some_condition){
         System.exit(0);
           }
           //some code    
         }
}
```

and i want to filter test-case if it satisfies condition If(some_condition). For example if testFibParam is running with param 1,1 and satisfies condition If(some_condition) - I want to skip it, but with another params test-cases do not have to be skipped.

I have the following filter:

```
class PostDiscoveryFilterImpl implements PostDiscoveryFilter {

    @Override
    public FilterResult apply(TestDescriptor object) {
            final var source = (MethodSource) object.getSource().get();
            if (object.getUniqueId().toString().hashCode() == 1285025359) {
                return FilterResult.excluded("Some message");
            }
            return FilterResult.included("Some message");
    }
}
```

I know that hashcode 1285025359 belongs to parametrized test-case with param 1,1. And I want to filter it.
My laucher config is below:

```
LauncherConfig launcherConfig = LauncherConfig.builder()
                .enableTestEngineAutoRegistration(false)
                .enableTestExecutionListenerAutoRegistration(false)
                .enablePostDiscoveryFilterAutoRegistration(false)
                .addTestEngines(new JupiterTestEngine())
                .addTestEngines(new VintageTestEngine())
                .addPostDiscoveryFilters(new PostDiscoveryFilterImpl())
                .build();

Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create(launcherConfig);

LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
                .selectors(selectClass("SomeClassTest"))
                .filters(new PostDiscoveryFilterImpl2())
                .build();

launcher.execute(request);
```

I can make it work with JUnit4, but can't do this with JUnit5. I compared JUnit4 and JUnit5 and had found that they have different TestDescriptor's in apply method in PostDiscoveryFilterImpl class. As I found,

TestTemplateTestDescriptor: [engine:junit-jupiter]/[SomeClassTest]/[test-template:testFibParam(java.lang.String)] was used in JUnit5

And this was appered once.

In Junit4 was used:

VintageTestDescriptor: [engine:junit-vintage]/[runner:SomeClassTest]/[test:%5B0%5D]/[test:testFibParam%5B0%5D(SomeClassTest)]

VintageTestDescriptor: [engine:junit-vintage]/[runner:SomeClassTest]/[test:%5B1%5D]/[test:testFibParam%5B0%5D(SomeClassTest)]

etc...

And this was appered for every param.

How can I make similar filtration of parametrized test-case with definite param ?

Comment: What you’re trying to do is really involved and you may or may not be able to make it work that way..Let’s make one step back: What do you want to achieve with it? Why filter out a test that you could just not include in the first place?

Comment: @johanneslink  Hello! 1) Our tool must run test's and if test-case has "System.exit(0);" or infinite loop this tool must restart itself, exclude this test-case and run test-cases without this test-case. I want to achieve this behavior at this stage  2) Unfortunately, i didn't understand your second question... Can you explain please how  can I exclude test-case with definite param in parametrized test without filter ? At the same time, I need to run this test-case with another params, which don't lead to "System.exit(0)" or infinite loop.

Comment: I have the same usecase and to answer @johanneslink question. I'm writing a library which evaluates a test-suite and filters future runs based on historic data. The dynamic tests belong to the client's project, not my library.  It needs to be able to filter any test that executes. I suspect this is missing feature in Junit 5 though?